# Android convert int number from mysql database into time format

Tags: java, android, mysql

How do i able to convert from an integer number that is get from mysql database into time format? Here are my java files

**parking_records.java with arrayAdapter**

```
public class parking_records extends ArrayAdapter<String> {
private String[] Parking_Start_Time;
private String[] Parking_End_Time;
private String[] Duration;

private Activity context;

public parking_records(Activity context, String[] Parking_Start_Time, String[] Parking_End_Time, String[] Duration) {
    super(context, R.layout.fragment_parking_record, Parking_Start_Time);
    this.context = context;
    this.Parking_Start_Time = Parking_Start_Time;
    this.Parking_End_Time = Parking_End_Time;
    this.Duration = Duration;
}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    LayoutInflater inflater = context.getLayoutInflater();
    View listViewItem = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_parking_record, null, true);
    TextView textViewPRd = (TextView) listViewItem.findViewById(R.id.textViewPRd);
    TextView textViewPRd1 = (TextView) listViewItem.findViewById(R.id.textViewPRd1);
    TextView textViewPRr = (TextView) listViewItem.findViewById(R.id.textViewPRr);

    textViewPRd.setText(Parking_Start_Time[position]);
    textViewPRd1.setText(Parking_End_Time[position]);
    textViewPRr.setText(Duration[position]);

    return listViewItem;
}
}
```

**Parking_Records.java**

```
public class Parking_Records {

public static String[] Parking_Start_Time;
public static String[] Parking_End_Time;
public static String[] Duration;

public static final String JSON_ARRAY = "result";
public static final String KEY_ParkStartTime = "Parking_Start_Time";
public static final String KEY_ParkEndTime = "Parking_End_Time";
public static final String KEY_ParkDuration = "Duration";


private JSONArray users = null;

private String json;

public Parking_Records(String json){
    this.json = json;
}

public void parseJSON(){
    JSONObject jsonObject=null;
    try {
        jsonObject = new JSONObject(json);
        users = jsonObject.getJSONArray(JSON_ARRAY);

        Parking_Start_Time = new String[users.length()];
        Parking_End_Time = new String[users.length()];
        Duration = new String[users.length()];


        for(int i=0;i<users.length();i++){
            JSONObject jo = users.getJSONObject(i);
            Parking_Start_Time[i] = jo.getString(KEY_ParkStartTime);
            Parking_End_Time[i] = jo.getString(KEY_ParkEndTime);
            Duration[i] = jo.getString(KEY_ParkDuration);

        }
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
}
```

**Main Parking_Records_Fragment.java**

```
public class ParkingRecordFragment extends Fragment implements View.OnClickListener, SwipeRefreshLayout.OnRefreshListener {

ProgressDialog dialog;

String url;

SessionManager session;
private String Username;
private String Acc_Pass;
SharedPreferences shared;
private SwipeRefreshLayout mSwipeRefreshLayout;

public ParkingRecordFragment() {
    // Required empty public constructor
}

private ListView listView;

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // Inflate the layout for this fragment
    ((AppCompatActivity)getActivity()).getSupportActionBar().setTitle("Parking Record");
    // Session class instance
    session = new SessionManager(getActivity().getApplicationContext());

    dialog = new ProgressDialog(getActivity());
    dialog.setMessage("Loading....");
    dialog.show();

    View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_listview_parking_records, container, false);

    listView = (ListView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.listView);
    listView.setEmptyView(rootView.findViewById(R.id.empty_list_item));
    mSwipeRefreshLayout = (SwipeRefreshLayout) rootView.findViewById(R.id.swipe_refresh_layout);
    mSwipeRefreshLayout.setOnRefreshListener(this);

    mSwipeRefreshLayout.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            mSwipeRefreshLayout.setRefreshing(false);
            sendRequest(Username, Acc_Pass);
        }
    }, 1000);

    sendRequest(Username, Acc_Pass);
    shared= getActivity().getSharedPreferences("Mypref", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);

    return rootView;

}

@Override
public void onRefresh() {
    sendRequest(Username, Acc_Pass);
}

private void sendRequest(String Username, String Acc_Pass){

    HashMap<String, String> user = session.getUserDetails();
    Username = user.get(SessionManager.KEY_USERNAME);
    Acc_Pass = user.get(SessionManager.KEY_PASSWORD);

    RequestQueue requestQueue = VolleyController.getInstance(getActivity().getApplicationContext()).getRequestQueue();

    String url = "http://192.168.1.5/json_parking_records2.php?Username="+Username+"&Acc_Pass="+Acc_Pass+"";
    url = url.replaceAll(" ", "%20");
    try {
        URL sourceUrl = new URL(url);
    } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    Log.i("Getting url info",""+url);

    StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.GET, url, new Response.Listener<String>() {

        @Override
        public void onResponse(String response) {
            showJSON(response);
            dialog.dismiss();
            mSwipeRefreshLayout.setRefreshing(false);
        }
    }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
        @Override
        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
            Toast.makeText(getActivity().getApplicationContext(),error.getMessage(),Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            dialog.dismiss();
        }
    });

    requestQueue.add(stringRequest);
}

private void showJSON(String json){
    Parking_Records pj = new Parking_Records(json);
    pj.parseJSON();
    parking_records cl = new parking_records(getActivity(),  Parking_Records.Parking_Start_Time, Parking_Records.Parking_End_Time, Parking_Records.Duration);
    listView.setAdapter(cl);
}

@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    sendRequest(Username, Acc_Pass);
}
}
```

[Android screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AhH52.png)

So right now i've been struggling of how do i able to convert from an integer number to a time format. Please guide me. Thanks

Comment: Is your integer a timestamp?Please show some example of the value which you need to convert??

Comment: There is a simple method to convert time in Long to time stamp in java.

Comment: I'm sorry, do you mean in my android or database? If in database, then it is not a timestamp, it just a simple integer value, and if you mean my android, then it is not a timestamp as well, my android `.xml` file is a textview and in all of the java code are using `String`. The value that i need to convert is the `Duration`, i have included the screenshot as well, which mean i want to convert that `Total duration` of `49` into `0hr 0min 49sec`

Answer (score 0):

I have solved my question on my own successfully. Here is the code.

```
textViewPRr.setText(String.format("%d:%02d:%02d", (Duration[position]/3600), (Duration[position]%3600)/60, (Duration[position]%60)));
```

I set that in **parking_records.java with arrayAdapter**

Hope that this answer can help others!